# Register-PSFLoggingProvider permanently | PSFramework module

Tags: javascript, logging

I want to register a **new logging provider** to the PSFramework logging system.

What I use is the following command :

```
Register-PSFLoggingProvider -Name "Mail" -Enabled -MessageEvent $message_Event
Install-PSFLoggingProvider -Name "Mail"
```

It works fine as demonstrated by the following command :

```
Get-PSFLoggingProvider

Name              Enabled ProviderVersion IncludeModules ExcludeModules IncludeTags ExcludeTags Initialized InstallationOptional
----              ------- --------------- -------------- -------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------
filesystem        True    Version_1       {}             {}             {}          {}          True        True
Mail              True    Version_1       {}             {}             {}          {}          True        False
AzureLogAnalytics False   Version_2       {}             {}             {}          {}          False       False
console           False   Version_2       {}             {}             {}          {}          False       False
eventlog          False   Version_2       {}             {}             {}          {}          False       False
gelf              False   Version_2       {}             {}             {}          {}          False       False
logfile           False   Version_2       {}             {}             {}          {}          False       False
splunk            False   Version_2       {}             {}             {}          {}          False       False
Sql               False   Version_2       {}             {}             {}          {}          False       False
```

My problem is that when **I switch consoles**, the "Mail" provider is no longer in the list.

```
Name              Enabled ProviderVersion IncludeModules ExcludeModules IncludeTags ExcludeTags Initialized InstallationOptional
----              ------- --------------- -------------- -------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------
filesystem        True    Version_1       {}             {}             {}          {}          False       True
AzureLogAnalytics False   Version_2       {}             {}             {}          {}          False       False
console           False   Version_2       {}             {}             {}          {}          False       False
eventlog          False   Version_2       {}             {}             {}          {}          False       False
gelf              False   Version_2       {}             {}             {}          {}          False       False
logfile           False   Version_2       {}             {}             {}          {}          False       False
splunk            False   Version_2       {}             {}             {}          {}          False       False
Sql               False   Version_2       {}             {}             {}          {}          False       False
```

I would like to know if there is a way to **save the provider permanently.**

Thanks for your help !